# Deserializing XML to C# Object returning null values

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml

When trying to get the values ​​from the XML text that comes from a WebService, the values ​​are null as the image below.

#### Code

```
string texto = 
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + 
    "<EnviarLoteRpsResposta xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"+
    "   <NumeroLote>3774</NumeroLote>" +
    "   <DataRecebimento>2014-09-03T23:03:57.3428675-03:00</DataRecebimento>" +
    "   <Protocolo>635453822373428675</Protocolo>" +
    "</EnviarLoteRpsResposta>";
            
XmlRootAttribute rootAttribute = new XmlRootAttribute("EnviarLoteRpsResposta");
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WS.NF.EnviarLoteRpsResposta), rootAttribute);
WS.NF.EnviarLoteRpsResposta ei = (WS.NF.EnviarLoteRpsResposta)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(texto));
```

#### Return variabble `ei`

[image]

#### Edit

From what I saw, the return is not the `ListaMensagemRetorno` field. Is this the problem?

#### Service Reference

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/")]
public partial class EnviarLoteRpsResposta {
        
    private System.Nullable<ulong> numeroLoteField;
        
    private System.Nullable<System.DateTime> dataRecebimentoField;
        
    private string protocoloField;
        
    private MensagemRetorno[] listaMensagemRetornoField;
        
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<ulong> NumeroLote {
        get {
            return this.numeroLoteField;
        }
        set {
            this.numeroLoteField = value;
        }
    }
        
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public System.Nullable<System.DateTime> DataRecebimento {
        get {
            return this.dataRecebimentoField;
        }
        set {
            this.dataRecebimentoField = value;
        }
    }
        
    /// <remarks/>
    public string Protocolo {
        get {
            return this.protocoloField;
        }
        set {
            this.protocoloField = value;
        }
    }
        
    /// <remarks/>
    public MensagemRetorno[] ListaMensagemRetorno {
        get {
            return this.listaMensagemRetornoField;
        }
        set {
            this.listaMensagemRetornoField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check xml file generated have all data

Comment: @Seminda XML return not exist `ListaMensagemRetorno`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### The Problem

Based on your example, the problem here is you have different [`XML Namespace`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) declaration between the XML string you're trying to deserialize and the deserialized object itself.

In the XML string, the XML does not have an XML Namespace declaration for `EnviarLoteRpsResposta` (no default namespace):

```
string texto = 
    "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + 
    "<EnviarLoteRpsResposta xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"+
    "   <NumeroLote>3774</NumeroLote>" +
    "   <DataRecebimento>2014-09-03T23:03:57.3428675-03:00</DataRecebimento>" +
    "   <Protocolo>635453822373428675</Protocolo>" +
    "</EnviarLoteRpsResposta>";
```

While in your `EnviarLoteRpsResposta` class, the XML Namespace is declared as `http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/`:

```
...
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/")]
public partial class EnviarLoteRpsResposta { ... }
```

### The Workarounds

In order for the deserialization to work, you need to do **ONE** of the following:

1. Change the `EnviarLoteRpsResposta` class and remove the XML Namespace declaration:

   ```
   ...
   /* REMOVED [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/")] */
   public partial class EnviarLoteRpsResposta { ... }
   ```
2. Or... Change the web service and add the appropriate XML Namespace to the returned XML string:

   ```
   string texto = 
       "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + 
       "<EnviarLoteRpsResposta 
          xmlns=\"http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/\" 
          xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" 
          xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">"+
       "   <NumeroLote>3774</NumeroLote>" +
       "   <DataRecebimento>2014-09-03T23:03:57.3428675-03:00</DataRecebimento>" +
       "   <Protocolo>635453822373428675</Protocolo>" +
       "</EnviarLoteRpsResposta>";
   ```

   Then slightly change the code to deserialize the XML string to:

   ```
    ...
    XmlRootAttribute rootAttribute = new XmlRootAttribute("EnviarLoteRpsResposta") { Namespace = "http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/" };         
    ...
   ```
3. Or... Change the code for deserializing the XML string and add the approriate XML Namespace programmaticaly (no change to `EnviarLoteRpsResposta` class or the web service):

   ```
   ...
   NameTable nt = new NameTable();
   XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nt);
   nsmgr.AddNamespace(String.Empty, "http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/");
   XmlParserContext context = new XmlParserContext(nt, nsmgr, null, XmlSpace.None);

   XmlRootAttribute rootAttribute = new XmlRootAttribute("EnviarLoteRpsResposta") { Namespace = "http://www.e-governeapps2.com.br/" };
   XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(WS.NF.EnviarLoteRpsResposta), rootAttribute);
   WS.NF.EnviarLoteRpsResposta ei = (WS.NF.EnviarLoteRpsResposta)serializer.Deserialize(new XmlTextReader(texto, XmlNodeType.Element, context));
   ...
   ```